# Why does this button not rotate is visual studio?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, visual-studio

If you run this code snippet you will see a button. If you click on it, it will rotate. I have the exact same code in Visual Studio (as you can see in the picture below). However, when i debug the code or press 'view in browser (Google Chrome)' it doesn't work at all.

```js
$("#rotate").click(function () {
    if ($(this).css("transform") == 'none') {
        $(this).css("transform", "rotate(45deg)");
    } else {
        $(this).css("transform", "");
    }
});
```

```css
body {
}

#rotate {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/css.css" />
    <script src="scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/JavaScript.js"></script>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="rotate"></button>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Do you get any errors in your console?

Comment: Firstly, don't load jQuery twice

Comment: No errors, no warnings. It does show me the button. But it won't rotate

Comment: Why did you provide jQuery scripts twice?

Comment: Does not really matter. I tried it with the one I got from nuget, and I tried it with the one you will find on the web. In this case I tried both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you wrap your button binding inside `$(document).ready(function () { });`? That is not clear from your example because it works fine if it is.

Or place your javascript code beneath the button without the `&(document).ready` function, that also works because if it is above the button the browser will try to bind a button that does not exits yet.

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#rotate").click(function () {
                if ($(this).css("transform") == 'none') {
                    $(this).css("transform", "rotate(45deg)");
                } else {
                    $(this).css("transform", "");
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    <style>
        #rotate {
            width: 100px;
            height: 30px;
        }
    </style>
    <button id="rotate" type="button">button</button>
```